# What is the most effecient way to get and view commonly used data inside a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, relational-database, rails-activerecord

I have three models all associated with eachother via `has_many :through` method.

```
ProgramCategory
ProgramSubcategory
Program
```

Inside my application, I need to use ProgramCategory.title, ProgramSubcategory.title and Program.title very often. Lets say, there'll be a dynamic sidebar menu and it will look like this:

```
|- Shows (ProgramCategory)
  |- Action (ProgramSubcategory)
    |- Lost (Program)
    |- Games of Thrones (Program)
    |- Dexter (Program)
```

Since I'm aware of power of `application_controller`, `application_helper` and `partials`; I feel lost about combining all of these together to find the most appropriate way.

Where and how should I call my models? Where should I build my methods to have access it through all of my controllers? Should I simply create a partial and render it at `application` layout?

I need some expert enlightment, please...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This navigation bar is not a core part of the data you are showing, it will be more or less the same for all pages. Thus, it does not belong to the controller.

Make it a helper method, and cache its results in the view:

`app/helpers/sidebar_helper.rb`

```
module SidebarHelper
  def sidebar_data
    # blahblah, use any tag helper (include it here if necessary)
    # just remember to 
  end
end
```

`app/controllers/your_controller.rb`

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  helper :sidebar
  # ...
```

(or put the helper method in your application helper to have it available everywhere)

`app/views/application/_sidebar.html.haml`

```
- cache do
  # well, put here whatever you need to output the sidebar
  # use the sidebar_data, which should return precooked data on 
  # which you can build your nested <ul>s.
  # just indent it two spaces, so it's inside the "cache do" block
```

or `app/views/application/_sidebar.html.erb`

```
<% cache do %>
  same as above, don't worry about indentation
<% end -%>
```

and include the partial where appropriate

```
<%= render 'sidebar' %>
```

Comment: This approach makes sense. I'm gonna give it a try and inform you about the result. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I've just tried it this way: Firstly created an helper method as you told. Inside it, I created an instance variable for demonstration purpose. I added helper sidebar to my application_controller. And whenever I call sidebar_data method, I can show data inside whereever I want. BUT when I use <% cache do %>, nothing is shown. Should I activate something from config or what?

Comment: are you going to answer my question, please?

Comment: Maybe you are not following correctly the cache guide. Ensure you read and understand this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: @scaryguy are you able to get the sidebar without the "cache do" snippet? The use of cache is just a suggestion to optimize the usage of the snippet, but you need to be able to show something without the "cache" part.

Comment: As I had told in my previous comment, I get what I want without 'cache do'. My answer request was about how to do it with cache do.

Comment: Try using an argument to the cache method: `cache("sidebar", :expires_in => 1.hour) do`

Answer (score 0):

If this sidebar shows in every view throughout your application, you can it to your application layout. Then add a before filter in your application controller to get the data, this will get executed for each action in every controller that inherits from application controller. You can also restrict it to specific actions, only `:index`, and `:show` (for each controller) for example.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :get_side_bar, :only => [:index, :show]

  def get_side_bar
    #@sidebar = some code
  end
end
```

Then you can use helper method (if needed) and render `@sidebar` in your application layout.

If you need to skip this action for some controllers you can do that as well, this one will skip application controller before filter for anything but index inside of the OtherController:

```
class OtherController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :get_side_bar, :except => [:index]
end
```

Comment: I wont need sidebar in some cases. You recommend me to use ':only' attribute but how can I restrict it for different contollers? I guess :only works wıth only current controller's actions?

Comment: Added skipping code to the answer. :only is optional, if you want it to run on 90% of your actions, it's easier to not use :only and to skip before filter on those 10% of cases